# Customised Google Cloudshell image does not launch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Customised Google Cloud Shell image fails to launch, error is *'Cloud Shell is experiencing some issues provisioning a VM to you. Please try again in a few minutes'*.  Repeated attempts to launch also fail.

I created a custom Google Cloudshell Image with an Ansible lab environment and setup tutorial.  When  this was tested approximately 10 days ago, it seemed to work as expected.   Setup was performed using the following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/customizing-container-image)

Project is hosted with the 'Open in Google Cloud Shell' button [here](https://github.com/spurin/diveintoansible-lab-gcp-cloudshell)

For convenience, this is the launch button as a [link](https://ssh.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/editor?cloudshell_image=gcr.io/diveintoansible/diveintoansible-lab-gcp-cloudshell&cloudshell_git_repo=https://github.com/spurin/diveintoansible-lab-gcp-cloudshell.git&cloudshell_tutorial=tutorial.md&shellonly=true)

The customised Cloud Shell image is hosted at gcr.io/diveintoansible/diveintoansible-lab-gcp-cloudshell

I've checked the permissions and these appear to be open to the public as desired.

Any advice on resolving this, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens because the base image is out of date. If your image worked a few weeks ago, you probably just need to rebuild it.

Comment: Adrian, thanks so much for your help and feedback on this.  After updating the image it worked perfectly.  I did then subsequently find a couple of weeks later, the same issue occurred.  Again, updating the image fixed the issue.  For those who encounter this problem, you'll need to consider regular updates that incorporate the base image.